# Remove a line from a string withing variable without leaving new lines

Tags: regex, powershell

Writing string to a RichTextBox with the following code

```
$TextBox.text = "`r`n Some Text `r`n" + $TextBox.text
```

Under certain circumstances, I need to delete a specific line from the text. The problem, I manage to find and delete the line but the rest of the text moves only 1 line up instead of 2

```
$TextBox.text = (($TextBox.text -split "`n") | ? {$_ -notmatch 'WordToSearch'}) -join "`n"
```

As I said, it removes the line, but an unnecessary new line still remains. How can I remove it too without using array or other complicated way?

For example, this is how the text looks:

```
\\empty line
row 1, some text
\\empty line
row 2, some text
\\empty line
```

After my attempt of deleting row 1, it looks like this:

```
\\empty line
\\empty line
row 2, some text
\\empty line
```

Expected:

```
\\empty line
row 2, some text
\\empty line
```

Comment: If the first element in the Rich Text at [0] is the empty line, you could use a .Remove() method on it. Not sure off hand if RTB's are a collection or just one long array of strings

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to remove blank lines from a string:

```
$str = "Line 1`r`n`r`n`r`nLine 4`r`n`r`nLine 6"
while ( $str -match "`r`n`r`n" ) {
  $str = $str -replace "`r`n`r`n","`r`n"
}
$str
# now $str contains only "Line 1", "Line 4", and "Line 6"
```

Comment: This is not the expected result. For the matter, I need to replace Line 6 with 4. `r`n`r`n`r`n there will be no such situation from the first place

Comment: My description did not claim to be the answer to your specific question but is a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `-replace` and then `.trim()` to ensure you don't end up with multiple blank lines (if the line to remove is the last one) then add your final blank line back in with `` +'`r`n' ``

```powershell
$find = "row 1"
$TextBox.text = ($TextBox.text -replace "(?mi)^.*$find.*`$(`r?`n)*",'').trim()+'`r`n'
```

Comment: This method deletes all new lines

Comment: It removes them all then appends one back to ensure there is still a trailing one.